# Android: 3D-transform an object

Tags: android, kotlin, canvas, 3d, matrix-transform

In an Android app I have an object that is created through a custom view. It basically has a rectangular shape. I want to apply a 3D transformation that makes it look like this:

[image: what i have vs. what i want]

In the `draw()` function I have tried various things like this:

```html
override fun draw(canvas: Canvas?) {

    super.draw(canvas)
    
    val matrix = Matrix()
    var pivX = myWidth / 2.0f
    var pivY = myHeight /1.0f
    matrix.setSkew(1f, 0f, pivX, pivY);

    canvas?.withMatrix(matrix) {
        drawPath(path(-150F), paint())
        drawPath(path(150F), paint())
    }

}
```

I couldn't make it work though. Where's my mistake? What am I missing?